# jupyternotebookにNbextensionsをインストールしたが、メニューにタブが表示されません。

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

anaconda,jupyternotebookを使っております。
nbextensionが便利そうなので、インストールしてみました。
（ダウンロードしてカレントフォルダーにおきました）。
anacondaのナビゲーターで確認すると、次の画像のように
installedのリストに表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、jupyternotebookのメイン画面にNbextensionsタブが表示されません。

どうすれば、表示されるでしょうか？

ちゃんとインストールされていないのでしょうか？

<追記2018/10/24>
この質問の趣旨から外れますが、ここ最近jupyter notebookを使う際はterminalから"jupyter notebook"と打ち込んで起動しておりましたので気づかなかったのですが、
anaconda navigatorのタブからjupyter notebookが起動しなくなっている状況を確認しました。何か、競合しているのか？anaconda navigatorを一度再インストールしてみるか？
タブをクリックすると、進行状況を示すグリーンのバロメーターは動き出すのですが、その後、ブラウザが立ち上がりません。以前は、アナコンダのタブからも普通に立ち上がっていたのですが。

Comment: 「ダウンロードしてカレントフォルダーにおきました」の具体的な手順を教えて下さい。[ここ](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions)を読むと、`conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`でインストール可能なようですが。

Comment: コメント欄記載の方法でインストールしました。Mac環境。ターミナルで上記を再度実行すると、既にインストールされていますとメッセージが表示されます。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく、[このバグ](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator/pull/85/commits/4e622d576432286df8d15e5a82c1554f9ecc6b66)が原因だと思います。

私の環境では、この`main.js`ファイルを直接修正したら、タブが表示されるようになりました。

Comment: 私の該当ファイルを調べると既に"  var $ = require('jquery');"になっておりました。(jqueryui --> jquery)

Comment: うーん、では、`jupyter nbextension enable <nbextension require path>`を実行しても、変わりませんか？

Comment: anacondaのタブからjupyter notebook起動すらできなくなったので、一旦、anacondaをアンインストールしました。現在、terminalからコマンドで立ち上げてます。後日、再インストールしてみます。